# asynchronous method calling within asp.net Web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to call a web method (job1) in an asp.net web service, then from within this webmethod call a procedure (job2) asyncronously. job 1 shouldnt have to wait for job2 to complete.

whats the best way to do this? (.net 4.5)

Comment: Can you provide some more context to this? Your question is rather vague. Do you have some code you've tried that doesn't work to share in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery ajax function to call method of web service.

```
    $.ajax({ 
             url: "test.html",
             context: document.body,
             async: true
         });
```

by default async is true and this will call method asynchronously.

For calling store procedure asynchronously check the below link:

[ADO.NET Asynchronous SQL Calls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42266/ADO-NET-Asynchronous-SQL-Calls)